# Windows Batch Variables Cramming Together

Tags: windows, batch-file

Ok, so to speed up my process of bringing my photos into my folder structure the way I want I've been trying to make a Batch file to convert them. This actual batch is being called from my VBScript that makes all of my target folders the way I want, and is supposed to invoke the converter so that I get each file in every subfolder, no matter the folder names. But when I run it I get some strange results. I hope someone can help me out.

```
@ECHO OFF

REM DNGConvert.CMD
REM Converts Raw Files to DNG Files

REM -----------------------------
REM   Parameters
REM -----------------------------
REM 1 = Source Drive
REM 2 = TargetFolder

REM -----------------------------
REM  Constants
REM -----------------------------
SET RawFormats=(*.NEF,*.CR2)
SET DNGLocation=C:\Progra~2\Adobe\DNGConv.exe -p2 -fl -d

for /r %1 %%i in %RawFormats% do %DNGLocation% %2% " %%i"
```

When it runs I'm getting this for the command line...

```
C:\Progra~2\Adobe\DNGConv.exe -p2 -fl -d d:\tempi"
```

when I actually want the very last thing to be the actual file names. Is there anyone that can help me?

Comment: Did you meant for this `%2%` to be this: `%2`

Answer (score 0):

Squashman called the first issue. Input parameters are always only prefaced by a %, not surrounded. So, `%1`, like you have, but also `%2`.

Second, for the destination folder, it might or might not be necessary depending on how you send the input in, but you might wish to use `"%~2"`, which will guarantee that the parameter is always surrounded in a single pair of quotes. The same for `"%%~i"`. You will definitely need those quotes if there are spaces in the paths of your source images, because `for /r` does not return them.